# Sticky tabbar with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

The situation looks like this:
[image]

My `MainViewController` consists of:

1. HeaderView. Height: 260 (without Tabbar: 200)
2. Tabbar which is a simple `UIView` extension and is part of the Header. Height: 60
3. `UIPageViewController` located right under the tabbar which contains 3 tableviews (for each tab one tableview)
4. All that is in a `UIScrollView`

My goal is to scroll the whole view to the top so only the tabbar stays visible (it should stick to the top) and then only the UITableView should be scrolled.

My approach is simple:

In my TableView controller I have:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TableViewScrolled"), object: nil)
}
```

In my MainViewController I add an observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(self.handleScroll),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TableViewScrolled"),
                                       object: nil)
```

Each time I scroll the TableView the `MainViewController` gets notified and in the `handleScroll` method I do something like this:

```
@objc private func handleScroll(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
}
```

This works only partially. The effect looks like this:
https://i.gyazo.com/b1f78c43f6847167295201f60731f274.mp4

The problem is that the TableView scrolls faster than the Header (as seen in the video above). Why is it happening? How to solve this problem?

Comment: just add `Segment` header in section in section thats it ,,,, it will stick at the Top

Comment: @Dhiru I don't understand what You mean. Can You elaborate on this?

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: Did u find solution?